# SSH connection refused

Tags: ssh, centos

I have a CentOS Linux server with a SSH connection. It works perfectly but from time to time, the server refuses the connection.

If I reboot the server, I can SSH again.

What could be wrong?

Comment: What do you have in the logs?

Comment: what log should I check?

Comment: `/var/log/messages` and the other stuff in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running `sshd` on the server in debug mode (`-d`, you can go up to `-ddd`) to get additional info. You can do this even remotely if don't happen to have the server under your table: log in, and then you can start another sshd instance on a different port with the `-p` option and try to log on into this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Check to log on the server:

```
grep -Ri ssh /var/log/*
```

and also use SSH with more verbosity on the client:

```
ssh -vvv user@server
```